# Mandar a imprimir PDF en impresora en red, cambiando propiedades en C#

Tags: c#, pdf

Tengo un problema al tratar de cambiar la configuración de las impresoras en red al mandar un PDF. Si imprime el documento pero quiero cambiar la orientación de la hoja, la impresión a doble cara, etc. Según investigue con hacer esto debería salir cualquier opción que modifique:

```
//Ejemplo para permitir doble cara
PrinterSettings op = new PrinterSettings();
op.Duplex = Duplex.Vertical;
```

Si imprime pero no en doble cara en este caso.
¿Existe alguna otra forma?

Comment: para el sentido de la hoja puedes usar "op.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true"

Comment: Para doble cara te sugiero revisar "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?view=netframework-4.8#constructors"

Comment: @Iva92 revisa si tu impresora soporta impresión "doble cara".

Answer (score 0):

Precisamente se realiza mediante la propiedad [Duplex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.duplex?view=netframework-4.8) definiendo:

```
Duplex.Horizontal   Double-sided, impresion horizontal.
```

o también:

```
Duplex.Vertical   Double-sided, impresión vertical.
```

pero debes comprobar que soporta este tipo de impresión mediante [CanDuplex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.canduplex?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_CanDuplex) :

```
        PrinterSettings op = new PrinterSettings();

        if (op.CanDuplex == true) //¿soporta impresión por los 2 lados?
        {
            op.Duplex = Duplex.Vertical;             
        }else{
          MessageBox.Show("Double-sided, impresión vertical NO soportada!");
        }
```

Para asegurar detecte la impresión por ambos lados y esta se pueda aplicar te sugiero revisar la configuración de la impresora, asegura que tu puedas tener acceso a esta propiedad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que en ocasiones el administrador puede desactivar estas propiedades para los clientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de hecho si hago esa validación pero aun así no lo imprime de esa manera. Incluso aunque imprima un documento de una sola hoja y cambio la orientación de la hoja o el numero de copias no lo hace. Me pregunto si tiene que ver el propio formato PDF o porque la impresora esta en red.

Comment: estas definiendo mediante .PrinterSettings.PrinterName = el nombre de la impresora en la cual pruebas? He usado este método y realiza la impresión sin problema, te sugiero revisar si la impresora en verdad tiene la propiedad "Print on both sides" y puedes cambiar tu esta configuración, agregué más información a mi respuesta.